FastApi Streaming Response with Partitioned Parquet File
I am trying to create a FastAPI GET endpoint that serves up a parquet octet stream to the client (assumed to be a python client library that turns it into a pandas dataframe).
The parquet file is partitioned and lives on the filesystem and I'm trying to get around gobbling it up into memory and writing it out into a standard FastAPI response using io.BytesIO.
I was loodking into the StreamingResponse and got it to work with a single partition, which looks like so:
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import pyarrow as pa
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper


@router.get("/")
async def get() -> StreamingResponse:
    path = "some/path/parquet.parquet/part-0.parquet"
    return StreamingResponse(
        FileWrapper(pa.input_stream(path),
        media_type="application/octet-stream",
    )


This works just fine but obviously I need to be able to stream back if the parquet has multiple partitions to it. One way I was thinking about it is to chain the FileWrapper against multiple paths, like so:
class MultiFileWrapper:

    def __init__(self, paths: list[Path]):
        self.paths = paths
        self.delegate = FileWrapper(pa.input_stream(self.paths.pop(0)))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.delegate.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            if self.paths:
                self.delegate = FileWrapper(pa.input_stream(self.paths.pop(0)))
                return self.delegate.__next__()
            else:
                raise

@router.get("/")
async def get() -> StreamingResponse:
    # I'd get this through some ls in the real world
    paths = [
      Path("some/path/parquet.parquet/part-0.parquet"), 
      Path("some/path/parquet.parquet/part-1.parquet"])
    ]

    return StreamingResponse(
        MultiFileWrapper(paths),
        media_type="application/octet-stream",
    )

On server side the streaming part works but it seams that the byte stream is not meant to look like this because when I try to read it back on the client like so:
pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(response.content), engine="pyarrow")

it blows up with an unsavory exception
OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: No more data to read.
Deserializing page header failed.

Overall I think I need to turn the parquet parts into one continuous stream as opposed to a chained stream of each part but I can't find anything online on how to do that. Pyarrow has some sort of StreamReader but it's a bit elusive to me how to use it and if it's suitable for this usecase.
